# send Issues to JIRA from an application

Tags: curl, jira

I want to send the issues of an application to JIRA. As I have searched and found some REST API of JIRA which send issues via Curl but I am not able to understand the different parameter used in Curl command .

Please give any solution either using Curl or any other method.
Please help me out. I have been struggling for a week.

EDIT:

> curl -D- -u abc:1234 -X POST https://*******.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue --data ' { "fields": { "project": { "key": "HELLOWORLD" }, "summary": "Test-RestAPI", "description": "Creating Task using project keys and issue type names using the REST API", "issuetype": { "name": "Task" }, "customfield_10200": "ABC", "customfield_10300": "ABCD" } }' -H "Content-Type: application/json"

What is abc:1234 and ****** in this Curl command?

Comment: have you looked at the man page for curl to understand the parameters ?

Comment: You need to explain what you have tried and why it failed, so that we can assess how much you already know and how much needs to be explained. Otherwise, you will be advised to read the manual...

Comment: curl -D- -u abc:1234 -X POST  https://*******.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue --data '
{
    "fields": {
        "project": { 
            "key": "HELLOWORLD"
        },
        "summary": "Test-RestAPI",
        "description": "Creating Task using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
        "issuetype": {
            "name": "Task"
        },
        "customfield_10200": "ABC",
        "customfield_10300": "ABCD"
    }
}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
what is  abc:1234  and  ****** in this  Curl command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple example of creation of an issue, in this case a Story.

```
curl -d "{\"fields\":{\"project\":{\"key\":\"project_key\"}, \"summary\": \"Test curl\", \"issuetype\": {\"name\": \"Story\"}}}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -u Username:Password https://jira.com/rest/api/2/issue -k
```

where:

- `-d` means the data to send
- `-H` the header
- `Username:Password` your username and password

[Here](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/issue-createIssue) you find how to create the correct JSON to send via the REST API.

This should give you a base on how to create issues via curl.

Comment: @arpan yes, your credentials

Comment: Thanks I am trying.

Comment: Please can you tell what is project_key ??

without giving project key i got following Response:

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @arpan is the project key of the project where you want to create the issue.  For example if you have some issue which key is `software-21` the key of the project is `software`

Comment: Thank you @Roberto for explanation and for your time :) .